# Selenium: PhantomJS does not load dynamic content

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I am trying to scrape links from a page with dynamic contents. Everything works perfectly if I use a Chrome driver. But when I try my script with PhantomJS, the dynamic contents does not load (I've taken screenshots to verify that). If I wait specifically for an element to be visible, phantom will raise an timeout exception. Here is my code in python

```
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
    driver.set_window_size(1200, 1024)
    driver.get(main_url)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 90)
```

I really need a headless browser, so I cannot just go with the Chrome driver. Does anyone knows what is possibly going wrong?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you share the link you are trying to visit?

Comment: The website is not in English, which can be really annoying. Here is the link: http://wenshu.court.gov.cn/List/List?sorttype=1&conditions=searchWord+2+AJLX++%E6%A1%88%E4%BB%B6%E7%B1%BB%E5%9E%8B:%E6%B0%91%E4%BA%8B%E6%A1%88%E4%BB%B6

Comment: And the DOM element that you are trying to find is?

Comment: I am trying to get the urls by xpath: "//div[@class='wstitle']/a/@href".